# Import Django json into iPhone App

Tags: python, ios, json, django, swift

I am looking to import some Django json into my iphone app.  The following Django code:

```
def jsonfixture(request):

    data = StraightredFixture.objects.filter(fixturematchday=12)
    json_data = serializers.serialize('json', data, use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
    return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

produces the following json in my browser:

```
[{"fields": {"awayteamscore": 2, "hometeamscore": 1, "home_team": "Stoke", "away_team": "Burnley", "fixturematchday": 12, "soccerseason": 354, "fixturedate": "2014-11-22T15:00:00", "fixturestatus": "FINISHED"}, "model": "straightred.straightredfixture", "pk": 136932}, {"fields": {"awayteamscore": 1, "hometeamscore": 2, "home_team": "ManCity", "away_team": "Swans", "fixturematchday": 12, "soccerseason": 354, "fixturedate": "2014-11-22T15:00:00", "fixturestatus": "FINISHED"}, "model": "straightred.straightredfixture", "pk": 136930}, {"fields": {"awayteamscore": 0, "hometeamscore": 0, "home_team": "Foxes", "away_team": "Sunderland", "fixturematchday": 12, "soccerseason": 354, "fixturedate": "2014-11-22T15:00:00", "fixturestatus": "FINISHED"}, "model": "straightred.straightredfixture", "pk": 137852}, {"fields": {"awayteamscore": 1, "hometeamscore": 2, "home_team": "Everton", "away_team": "West Ham", "fixturematchday": 12, "soccerseason": 354, "fixturedate": "2014-11-22T15:00:00", "fixturestatus": "FINISHED"}, "model": "straightred.straightredfixture", "pk": 136929}, {"fields": {"awayteamscore": 0, "hometeamscore": 2, "home_team": "Chelsea", "away_team": "West Bromwich", "fixturematchday": 12, "soccerseason": 354, "fixturedate": "2014-11-22T15:00:00", "fixturestatus": "FINISHED"}, "model": "straightred.straightredfixture", "pk": 136928}, {"fields": {"awayteamscore": 0, "hometeamscore": 1, "home_team": "Newcastle", "away_team": "QPR", "fixturematchday": 12, "soccerseason": 354, "fixturedate": "2014-11-22T15:00:00", "fixturestatus": "FINISHED"}, "model": "straightred.straightredfixture", "pk": 136931}, {"fields": {"awayteamscore": 2, "hometeamscore": 1, "home_team": "Arsenal", "away_team": "ManU", "fixturematchday": 12, "soccerseason": 354, "fixturedate": "2014-11-22T17:30:00", "fixturestatus": "FINISHED"}, "model": "straightred.straightredfixture", "pk": 136927}, {"fields": {"awayteamscore": 1, "hometeamscore": 3, "home_team": "Crystal", "away_team": "Liverpool", "fixturematchday": 12, "soccerseason": 354, "fixturedate": "2014-11-23T13:30:00", "fixturestatus": "FINISHED"}, "model": "straightred.straightredfixture", "pk": 136926}, {"fields": {"awayteamscore": 2, "hometeamscore": 1, "home_team": "Hull", "away_team": "Spurs", "fixturematchday": 12, "soccerseason": 354, "fixturedate": "2014-11-23T16:00:00", "fixturestatus": "FINISHED"}, "model": "straightred.straightredfixture", "pk": 136925}, {"fields": {"awayteamscore": 1, "hometeamscore": 1, "home_team": "Aston Villa", "away_team": "Southampton", "fixturematchday": 12, "soccerseason": 354, "fixturedate": "2014-11-24T20:00:00", "fixturestatus": "FINISHED"}, "model": "straightred.straightredfixture", "pk": 136924}]
```

I then have the following swift code in xcode:

```
let url2 = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8000/straightred/jsonfixture")
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url2!)
var dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary
```

However, it errors at the third line in the code with error "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION".

Sadly I do not know if there is something wrong with the django json output or the swift xcode json import.  Any help on this would be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance, Alan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON data is an *array* of dictionaries, not a dictionary. *You have to cast the deserialization result as an NSArray instead of an NSDictionary.*

Change this line:

```
var dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary
```

with

```
var arr = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as NSArray
```

**Swift 2 update:**

Still the same idea but safer.

For simplicity, we can use `try?` with a multiple `if let`:

```
if let data = data,
    json = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []),
    arr = json as? NSArray {
    // use arr
}
```

And if you need to handle errors from NSJSONSerialization (or other throwing methods), then Do-Try-Catch is the way:

```
do {
    if let data = data,
        json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []),
        arr = json as? NSArray {
        // use arr
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

*Also, just a note: in your example you're using `NSData(contentsOfURL:)`. It's ok to use this for experimenting, but you should always use asynchronous methods like `NSURLSession` instead in real code.*

Comment: Simply as that!  Really appreciate the swift response.  Thank you.